# shap: plot function

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, shap

I try I would like to create a SHAP summary plot, colored by feature values when they are provided as follow :

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test_subset , feature_names=X_test_subset .columns, max_display=25)
```

But I got this error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py
>   in **call**(self, obj)
>       339                 pass
>       340             else:
>   --> 341                 return printer(obj)
>       342             # Finally look for special method names
>       343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py
>   in (fig)
>       242 
>       243     if 'png' in formats:
>   --> 244         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
>       245     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
>       246         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py
>   in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
>       126 
>       127     bytes_io = BytesIO()
>   --> 128     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
>       129     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
>       130     if fmt == 'svg':
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py
>   in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor,
>   orientation, format, **kwargs)    2210
>   orientation=orientation,    2211                     dryrun=True,
>   -> 2212                     **kwargs)    2213                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer    2214                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py
>   in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
>       515 
>       516     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
>   --> 517         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
>       518         renderer = self.get_renderer()
>       519         original_dpi = renderer.dpi
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py
>   in draw(self)
>       435             # if toolbar:
>       436             #     toolbar.set_cursor(cursors.WAIT)
>   --> 437             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
>       438             # A GUI class may be need to update a window using this draw, so
>       439             # don't forget to call the superclass.
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py
>   in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        53                 renderer.start_filter()
>        54 
>   ---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        56         finally:
>        57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py
>   in draw(self, renderer)    1491     1492
>   mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
>   -> 1493                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)    1494     1495
>   renderer.close_group('figure')
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py
>   in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists,
>   suppress_composite)
>       139     if not_composite or not has_images:
>       140         for a in artists:
>   --> 141             a.draw(renderer)
>       142     else:
>       143         # Composite any adjacent images together
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py
>   in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        53                 renderer.start_filter()
>        54 
>   ---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        56         finally:
>        57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py
>   in draw(self, renderer, inframe)    2633
>   renderer.stop_rasterizing()    2634 
>   -> 2635         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)    2636     2637         renderer.close_group('axes')
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py
>   in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists,
>   suppress_composite)
>       139     if not_composite or not has_images:
>       140         for a in artists:
>   --> 141             a.draw(renderer)
>       142     else:
>       143         # Composite any adjacent images together
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py
>   in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        53                 renderer.start_filter()
>        54 
>   ---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        56         finally:
>        57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py
>   in draw(self, renderer)
>       909     def draw(self, renderer):
>       910         self.set_sizes(self._sizes, self.figure.dpi)
>   --> 911         Collection.draw(self, renderer)
>       912 
>       913
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py
>   in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        53                 renderer.start_filter()
>        54 
>   ---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        56         finally:
>        57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py
>   in draw(self, renderer)
>       262         renderer.open_group(self.**class**.**name**, self.get_gid())
>       263 
>   --> 264         self.update_scalarmappable()
>       265 
>       266         transform, transOffset, offsets, paths = self._prepare_points()
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py
>   in update_scalarmappable(self)
>       806             return
>       807         if self._is_filled:
>   --> 808             self._facecolors = self.to_rgba(self._A, self._alpha)
>       809         elif self._is_stroked:
>       810             self._edgecolors = self.to_rgba(self._A, self._alpha)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.py
>   in to_rgba(self, x, alpha, bytes, norm)
>       272         x = ma.asarray(x)
>       273         if norm:
>   --> 274             x = self.norm(x)
>       275         rgba = self.cmap(x, alpha=alpha, bytes=bytes)
>       276         return rgba
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py
>   in **call**(self, value, clip)
>       945             result.fill(0)   # Or should it be all masked?  Or 0.5?
>       946         elif vmin > vmax:
>   --> 947             raise ValueError("minvalue must be less than or equal to maxvalue")
>       948         else:
>       949             if clip:
>
> ValueError: minvalue must be less than or equal to maxvalue

Comment: I am having the same issue, would like to see what the solution is.